# Mongodb findone document in array by object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can I get only 1 photo by `objectid`? I only need to get 1 Image detail from 1 post by photo but what i get is all photo of post.

**this is my db structure**

[image]

**and this is my code looks like:**

```
 Post.findOne({
  $and: [
    { photo: { $elemMatch: { _id: id } } }       ]
}).exec((err, post) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: err });
  }
  req.post = post;
  console.log(req.post);
  next();
});
```

what i get in req.post is only [].

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to get a photo by an id, regardless of what post it is, you can do `{ 'post.photo._id': id }` in your search condition

Comment: I still get all photos. Is it posible to get only 1 from photos by photo objectId ?

Comment: Im finally getting this one
[{
 "photo": [{
  "_id": "5d7dd20185251921882e2ba1",
    "data": "",
                "contentType":""
 }]
}]
Now my problem is I cant get the contentType. undefined on post.photo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator provides a way to alter the returned documents, in here coupled with [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) utilizing second parameter which is **projection** will achieve that.

```
Post.find(
  {},
  {
    _id: 0,
    photo: { $elemMatch: { _id: id } }
  }
);
```

**This will provide leaned documents with the promise: `.lean().exec()`:**

```
Post.find(
  {},
  {
    _id: 0,
    photo: { $elemMatch: { _id: id } }
  }
)
  .lean()
  .exec();
```

**NOTE:** `$elemMatch` behaviour is to return the first document where `photo`'s `id` matches.

Comment: It gives me this [ { photo: [ [Object] ] } ]. I cant get contentType

Comment: @kaks That object should contain all properties. You could try with `.lean().exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with aggregate instead of findOne:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

```
Post.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'photo._id': id } },
    { $unwind: "$photo" },
    { $match: { 'photo._id': id } },
]);
```

Maybe not the best, but single photo data is achievable.